# Elegant approach to get a CSV string from selected data rows in a datagrid

Tags: c#, csv, datarow

I have a datatable containing system profile names. This table is then assigned as the data source of a data grid where the administrator will mark multiple rows as selected.

I'd like to store the selected profile names as a comma separated string.
I was going to do it like this:

```
string AllowedProfiles = string.Empty;

// Retrieve the selected profiles from the data grid
DataRow[] profiles = (this.dgv_SecurityProfiles.DataSource as System.Data.DataTable).Select("profile_OK = 1");

// Ensure we have some data to assign to the CSV string
if( profiles != null && profiles.Length > 0 )
{
    // Build the CSV string of the selected names.
    foreach( DataRow row in profiles )
    {
        // Use the second column in the DataTable (first is the check column)
        AllowedProfiles += string.Format("{0},", row[1]); 
    }

    // Remove the last comma
    AllowedProfiles = AllowedProfiles.Substring(0, AllowedProfiles.Length - 1);
}
```

Whilst the above code works I don't feel it's the most elegant way forward.

Any suggestion on how I could improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this linq query

```
string AllowedProfiles = profiles.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, row) => current + string.Format(",{0}", row[1])).Remove(0,1);
```

Comment: That's exactly the sort of elegance I was looking for. Thank you. I think I'm going to need to learn Linq.